# Position child at bottom of parent until dynamic siblings fill parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an element that is a sibling of a `<ul>` that fills dynamically

```
<div>
    <ul>
    </ul>
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

I would like the `<p>` to be fixed at the bottom of the screen until the dynamic `<li>`s require it to be pushed down below the view.

I have tried the following but can not get the results I desire.

The element is in the correct position at the bottom and then gets pushed down but eventually gets consumed by its siblings.

```js
for(var i =0; i < 50; i++){
  var value = document.querySelector('input').value

  var node = document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");         // Create a text node
  node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
  document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
div {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <input type='text' value='dsaf'/>
  <ul>
  </ul>
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice how in the code snippet, the child paragraph gets pushed down by its siblings but is then overlapping with them.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to

Comment: Did you try running my code snippet?

Comment: add some margin-bottom to the ul

Comment: @TemaniAfif `margin-bottom` is does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this?

I added `padding-bottom:30px;` to the `div`

```js
for(var i =0; i < 25; i++){
  var value = document.querySelector('input').value

  var node = document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");         // Create a text node
  node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
  document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
div {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <input type='text' value='dsaf'/>
  <ul>
  </ul>
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```